# Initalize pyproj correctly

Tags: python, pyproj

I'm trying to initialize the pyproj transformer as laid out here: [Repeated transformations](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/advanced_examples.html#repeated-transformations). This seems like it should be pretty easy. I'm trying to go from NC stateplane to lon/lat.

https://epsg.io/3358

https://epsg.io/6318

```
import pyproj 
trans = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(3358, 6318)`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/MyUser/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-10-0c6306cf1b50>", line 1, in <module>
    pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(3358, 6318)
  File "/home/MyUser/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyproj/transformer.py", line 311, in from_crs
    CRS.from_user_input(crs_from),
  File "/home/MyUser/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyproj/crs/crs.py", line 440, in from_user_input
    return CRS(value, **kwargs)
  File "/home/MyUser/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyproj/crs/crs.py", line 296, in __init__
    super().__init__(projstring)
  File "pyproj/_crs.pyx", line 2338, in pyproj._crs._CRS.__init__
pyproj.exceptions.CRSError: Invalid projection: epsg:3358: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: cannot build projectedCRS 3358: cannot build geodeticCRS 4152: SQLite error on SELECT name, ellipsoid_auth_name, ellipsoid_code, prime_meridian_auth_name, prime_meridian_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, publication_date, deprecated FROM geodetic_datum WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column: publication_date)
```

Something seems off, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Did you install using pip/wheel? https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj/issues/605

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: I don't have this issue, I was pointing out a similar issue raised on the pyproj tracker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#internal-proj-error-sqlite-error-on-select

I think that you have multiple versions of PROJ installed on your system and it is mixing up which database to use.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is addressed in their own documentation here: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#internal-proj-error-sqlite-error-on-select

Using commands mentioned in their website to identify the path that has been set:

```
pyproj.datadir.get_data_dir()
pyproj.datadir.set_data_dir()
```

The correct path in my environment, which took a fair bit to find is as follows:

```
c:\\Users\\myname\\Anaconda3\\envs\\main\\lib\\site-packages\\pyproj\\proj_dir\\share\\proj
```

Answer (score 0):

I had conflicting versions of the proj.db. Check the value of the PROJ_LIB environment variable. Mine pointed to an installation of postgis. This helps to solve it: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/gotchas.html#internal-proj-error-sqlite-error-on-select

How did I find the path to the installation of `proj`?
I looked into this file `...Miniconda3\envs\<ENV>\conda-meta\proj-<VERSION>-h1cfcee-<VERSION>.json` and searched for `\pkgs\\proj`. Once found, I checked the versins of `PROJ` installed in this folder `C:...\Miniconda3\pkgs\`. There are folder named something like `proj-<VERSION>-h1cfcee-<VERSION>`. Make sure the folder name is the exact same name you found this file links to:  `...Miniconda3\envs\<ENV>\conda-meta\proj-<VERSION>-h1cfcee-<VERSION>.json`. Finally I set my environment variable to the version needed `...Miniconda3\pkgs\proj-<VERSION>-h1cfcee-<VERSION\Library\share\proj`.